# Is there any way to FORCIBLY allow the usage of '<' and/or '>' in XML files?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I have written a C# application that loads XML files, parses them and uses the information to run SQL queries and send the results to email distribution lists.

These XML files are usually created by END users.

Currently I have them replacing > and < with > and < in the SQL, of course being END users they sometime forget. In fact they ALWAYS forget. I'd prefer to keep the query in an XML file. So, is there ANY way to force/allow the use of these special characters in XML files?

Right now my user must type this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<report>
  <queries>
    <query>
       SELECT * FROM THETABLE WHERE THEVALUE &gt; 100
    </query>
  </queries>
</report>
```

I'd like them to be able to type this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<report>
  <queries>
    <query>
       SELECT * FROM THETABLE WHERE THEVALUE > 100
    </query>
  </queries>
</report>
```

Comment: Why are the users hand-editing XML files, instead of using a tool which then creates the XML? Note that `>` would be valid here anyway, IIRC - within an element, I think it's only `<` and `&` that have to be escaped.

Comment: Put it in a CDATA section, between `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` delimiters. How are you currently creating and writing the XML?

Comment: Yeah sure I suppose I could have the users use a separate tool to create these XML files. Have that tool convert the special characters in the SQL.

Comment: If you want the users to keep using their preferred format, you can use my regex solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap your queries in [`CDATA`](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<report>
  <queries>
    <query><![CDATA[
       SELECT * FROM THETABLE WHERE THEVALUE > 100
    ]]></query>
  </queries>
</report>
```

Comment: Yes this works.. not the solution I was hoping for but it's obviously the only right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp), text inside CDATA is not parsed, something like this :

```
<query><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM THETABLE WHERE THEVALUE > 100]]></query>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to surround the text with CDATA so it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<report>
  <queries>
    <query>
       <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM THETABLE WHERE THEVALUE > 100]]>
    </query>
  </queries>
</report>
```

This tells the parser that everything between  should be treated as text and should not be interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`CDATA`](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp). So:

```
<query><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM THETABLE WHERE THEVALUE > 100]]></query>
```

The text inside a *CDATA* section is ignored by the parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can preprocess the file with a regular expression which looks for < and > that doesn't belong to a tag, and replace them accordingly.

You can use this regex:

```
    (?sx)
    \s*
    (?:<\?.*?\?>)(?:\s*)
    (?:
     (?:<[^\s]*?>)\s*
     |(?:[^<>]*\s)
     |(?<lt><)
     |(?<gt>>)
    )*
    \s*
```

(Be aware that you must use single line and ignore whitespace options, as stablished by `(?sx)`.

This expression captures or the less than and greater than symbols which doesn't belong to the tags in the `lt` and `gt` groups.

You can replace the matches.

If you want to know how it works, this captures everything in named groups:

```
    (?sx)
    \s*
    (?<head><\?.*?\?>)(?:\s*)
    (?:
     (?<tag><[^\s]*?>)\s*
     |(?<others>[^<>]*\s)
     |(?<lt><)
     |(?<gt>>)
    )*
    \s*
```